# Getting aggregate ratio from a property from relationships with Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Let's say I have a graph like this (excuse the pseudo-code):

```
(A)-[:RSVP {reply:true}]->(X)

(B)-[:RSVP {reply:true}]->(X)

(C)-[:RSVP {reply:false}]->(X)
```

How do I get the ratio of positive responses? I'm expecting a result that will give me the acceptance ratio of 0.66.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using @FrobberOfBits' sample data, the following is a more general query that takes care of a couple of special cases (which would otherwise cause Cypher to have a "/ by zero" error).

1. If are no RSVPs, the query returns the string "No Matches".
2. If are no `false` RSVPs, the query returns the string "Infinity".
3. Otherwise, the query returns the ratio of yeses to nos.

   ```
   MATCH (X {label:"party time"})
   OPTIONAL MATCH (X)<-[:RSVP {reply:true}]-(yes)
   OPTIONAL MATCH (X)<-[:RSVP {reply:false}]-(no)
   WITH LENGTH(COLLECT(DISTINCT yes)) AS yeses, LENGTH(COLLECT(DISTINCT no)) AS nos
   RETURN CASE
     WHEN yeses = 0 AND nos = 0 THEN "No Matches"
     WHEN nos = 0 THEN "Infinity"
     ELSE TOFLOAT(yeses)/nos
   END;
   ```

To get the ratio that you originally asked for (ratio of yeses to the total number of responses), the query would be:

```
    MATCH (X {label:"party time"})
    OPTIONAL MATCH (X)<-[:RSVP {reply:true}]-(yes)
    OPTIONAL MATCH (X)<-[:RSVP {reply:false}]-(no)
    WITH LENGTH(COLLECT(DISTINCT yes)) AS yeses, LENGTH(COLLECT(DISTINCT no)) AS nos
    RETURN CASE
      WHEN yeses = 0 AND nos = 0 THEN "No Matches"
      ELSE TOFLOAT(yeses)/(yeses + nos)
    END;
```

Comment: Yeah, this is a more robust but very similar version of the query.  I was writing quickly and assumed OP wouldn't ask the question when there were none of a response (indicating an edge case where you'd get some NaN response)

Answer (score 2):

I mocked up your data this way:

```
CREATE (A), (B), (C), (X {label: "party time"})
MERGE (A)-[:RSVP {reply:true}]->(X)
MERGE (B)-[:RSVP {reply:true}]->(X)
MERGE (C)-[:RSVP {reply:false}]->(X);
```

Then, with this query, we can simply count the "yes's" and the "no's" separately, and create the ratio with simple division:

```
MATCH (X {label:"party time"})
MATCH (X)<-[:RSVP {reply:true}]-(yeses),
      (X)<-[:RSVP {reply:false}]-(nos)
RETURN count(distinct(yeses))/count(distinct(nos));
```

The answer I get is 2, because there are 2 yeses and 1 no.  (`2/1 => 2`)